# Is there a way to use expressions when doing aggregations (using Datatable)?

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

So do a count aggregation over terms with resuts looking like this:

```
term1   345
term2   249
term3   117
```

I would like to show  a second column that would represent a percentage of total count, ex:

```
term1   345  3.45%
term2   249  2.47%
term3   117  2.22%
```

Does Kibana support something like this?
Can I do something like this for example?

```
{ "script" : "doc['terms'].count/(TOTAL/100)" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this [issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2284) is still open. Lets hope it'll be available in the near future. +1 to make this bubble to the top.